# How to create HLS video with subtitle using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I need to convert mp4 video and subtitles and convert it to m3u8.

```
   ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i subtitle0.vtt -i subtitle1.vtt -c copy -c:s webvtt -c:s webvtt
    -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1 -map 2 
    -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -c:a aac -ar 48000 
    -filter:v:0 scale=w=480:h=360  -maxrate:v:0 600k -b:a:0 500k 
    -map "1:0" "-metadata:s:s:1" "language=heb" "-metadata:s:s:1" "handler_name=Hebrew"  "-metadata:s:s:1" "title=Hebrew" 
    -map "2:0" "-metadata:s:s:2" "language=eng" "-metadata:s:s:2" "handler_name=English" "-metadata:s:s:2" "title=English" 
    -var_stream_map v:0,a:0 stream_%v.m3u8
    -preset fast -hls_list_size 10 -threads 0 -f hls 
    -hls_time 3 -hls_flags independent_segments 
    -hls_segment_filename res/data%06d.ts
    -master_pl_name livestream.m3u8
    -y livestream-%v.m3u8
```

I've tried a lot of variants but all not working.
This is the error from the last one

```
At least one output file must be specified
```

Answer (score 0):

That error indicates that the commandline arguments aren't being parsed correctly. I recommend adding `-v debug` to your command, which will output debug data including how it parses the input arguments. My guess is the `"-metadata:s:s:1"` lines are messing up parsing because they have quotes around them.